# Start services in parallel

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have a script which checks if certain service on different servers is up, if it is not, the script should start the service.

The problem is, it doesn't start the services in parallel, instead it waits until each service is started.

Code:

```
$server_list = Get-Content -path D:\Path\list_of_servers.txt

$server_list | foreach { 
 (Get-Service -Name '*Service Name*' -computername $_) | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "Stopped"} | Set-Service -Status Running
}
```

I know it's due to the way the script is written, but maybe some of you have any suggestions how to make it better?

Cheers!

Comment: Which version of Powershell are you running? With V3 and V4 you can use `foreach -parallel`

Comment: Have you looked at using `Start-Job`?

Comment: @MickyBalladelli Sadly, we are using V2

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF No, I will check it out.

Comment: I've added an example of jobs in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of parallel processing using Powershell and Workflows:

```
$server_list = Get-Content -path D:\Path\list_of_servers.txt
workflow MyWorkflow
{
    foreach -parallel($s in $server_list) { 
        inlinescript { (Get-Service -Name '*Service Name*' -PSComputerName $s) | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "Stopped"} | Set-Service -Status Running
        }
    }
}
```

**Using Powershell V2 and jobs**

Untested code, but should be close:

```
$server_list = Get-Content -path D:\Path\list_of_servers.txt

$maxJobs = 5
$scriptblock = { 
(Get-Service -Name $args[1] -ComputerName $args[0]) | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "Stopped"} | Set-Service -Status Running
}

foreach ($s in $server_list)
{
    $arguments = @($s, $service)

    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })
    while ($running.Count -gt ($maxJobs -1)) {
        $done = Get-Job | Wait-Job -Any
        $running = @(Get-Job | ? {$_.State -eq 'Running'})
    }   
    start-job -scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $arguments
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: It'll work, but spinning up a background job just to restart a service seems a little heavy-handed from a resource perspective.